# Use website using Jsoup.connect() or other tech , but is it legal or not?

Tags: web-crawler, jsoup

> I get from a website using Jsoup.connect()
>
> When we access using the Jsoup or any other tech to request using our
>   peace of code, is this valid or legal??.

.

> The URL we trying to access using the Jsoup.connect("url") or other
>   Tech. so that url owner can put allegation on us to violation of any
>   kind of IT terms.

.

> Is this legal to access any kind of web like Private web, Social webs,
>   PSU webs, Governments webs from our peace of code and use their response for over development

.

Thanks.

Comment: You must read robots.txt of the site before crawling it. There are written permission for what you may read and should not

Comment: can we specify the Host list in robots.txt ? @S.Petrosov

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must read robots.txt of the site before crawling it. There are written permission for what you may read and should not

About /robots.txt

> Web site owners use the /robots.txt file to give instructions about
>   their site to web robots; this is called The Robots Exclusion Protocol.

It works likes this: a robot wants to vists a Web site URL, say http://www.example.com/welcome.html. Before it does so, it firsts checks for http://www.example.com/robots.txt, and finds:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

> The "User-agent: *" means this section applies to all robots.
>   The "Disallow: /" tells the robot that it should not visit any pages on
>   the site.

There are two important considerations when using /robots.txt:

1. Robots can ignore your /robots.txt. Especially malware robots that scan the web for security vulnerabilities, and email address harvesters used by spammers will pay no attention.
2. The /robots.txt file is a publicly available file. Anyone can see what sections of your server you don't want robots to use.
   So don't try to use /robots.txt to hide information.

More information about /robots.txt you can find here [/robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html)